ESP32 Serial Output
I am trying to get my ADC values in a comma seperated format. In doing so, I have tried to include #include "sstream" and when I go to build the project, I get the following error:
/home/dlaroche/ESP32C3_Dual_Wifi/main/continuous_read_main.c:5:10: fatal error: sstream: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <sstream>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

When using the autocomplete in VScode, it does identify or see the sstream as a possible include file, however, the compiler is seeming to have issues with the use of sstream. Is there any work around to this? Here is the code that is trying to utilize sstream:
while (1) {
    ret = adc_continuous_read(handle, result, EXAMPLE_READ_LEN, &ret_num, 0);

    // THIS SECTION OF CODE BELOW USES "sstream"
    stringstream ss;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (ret == ESP_OK) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ret_num; i += SOC_ADC_DIGI_RESULT_BYTES) {
            adc_digi_output_data_t *p = (adc_digi_output_data_t*)&result[i];
            uint32_t chan_num = EXAMPLE_ADC_GET_CHANNEL(p);
            uint32_t data = EXAMPLE_ADC_GET_DATA(p);
            if (chan_num < SOC_ADC_CHANNEL_NUM(EXAMPLE_ADC_UNIT)) {

              // THIS SECTION OF CODE USES "sstream"
              ss << chan_num << "," << data << ",";
              //////////////////////////////////////

            } 
        }

        // THIS SECTION OF CODE BELOW USES "sstream"
        std::string result_str = ss.str();
        if (!result_str.empty()) {
            result_str.pop_back();
        }
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ADC Values: %s", result_str.c_str());
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }
}


As far as I know sstream is a C++ library, and from the name of the file you are compiling, and the tag you added, you are using C.

Thank you for your response. That is a clear indication of why I am experiencing build issues. Do you know of another approach using a C library? Not too familiar with C.

The other C++ thing is std::string  If you are using C then you just need arrays of characters.  So instead of std::string result you might need char result[200] or something with as much space as you will use.

Instead of stringstream you should use sprintf to fill your string: https://onlinegdb.com/Xg_xrvdD3

I ended up using this code that uses #include <stdio.h>.
   while (1) {
       // Send the ADC buffer over USB
       if (buffer_index >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
           // Send buffer to USB
           for (size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
             printf("ADC0: %d, ADC1: %d\n", adc_buffer[i * 2], adc_buffer[i * 2 + 1]);
           }
           buffer_index = 0; // Reset buffer index
       }
       vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100)); // Adjust delay as needed
   }


If you have to use C then you can't use the sstream or string headers.
There may be a way to configure it to allow C++ so that you can use them,
but, in this answer, I will focus on writing C code instead of C++ code.
So instead of using
std::string result_str;

to define an empty string you need to use
char result_str[200] = "";

That will make a string C understands.
And instead of using
ss << chan_num << "," << data << ",";

to fill the string you need to use
sprintf(result_str+strlen(result_str), "%d,%d,", chan_num,data);

And instead of using
if (!result_str.empty())
    result_str.pop_back();

to remove the final comma you would use
if (strlen(result_str))
    result_str[strlen(result_str)-1] = '\0';

You can see a working version at https://onlinegdb.com/Xg_xrvdD3
